# How to give apache the right to write in the Document root on Mac Os 10.8 ( Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having a lot of issues with PHP and Apache while using os-x mountain lion. Basically my plugin needs wordpress to move some files but it always ask for ftp server credential, like if apache doesn't have permission to write those directories.

Apache is running with

> User daemon
>   Group daemon

if i do

> ls -lad htdocs/

i get

> drwxrwxr-x  7 root  staff  238 13 Ago 21:51 htdocs/

i'm using zend server ce 5.6. What should i do to make sure that apache has full rights to do everything? I would give it root access (it' my dev machine and i must get things working, so i don't care about security issues, but i don't know how to that, if i can do it in a cleaner why i'd be happy but i need this to work )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htdocs directory is owned by root, and in the group staff. User permissions on it are rwx, group permission are rwx, and world permissions are rx. So apache needs to be run as either user root or group staff to have full read/write/execute permissions. Otherwise change the owner and/or group of your htdocs directory to daemon and apache will have full rwx permissions. If you really don't care about security at all, just do chmod 777 htdocs (not recommended).

Comment: i had changed to 777 but it didn't work. did a chown to  daemon and worked. Thought you'd need some black magic for it but it was easy, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress isn't really checking if it has the right to write in a directory (it's the same for plugin installation), it's only checking if the user and group it's running through Apache is the same that the parent folder.

So the only way is indeed to chmod the folder to your Apache user/group